# Rails: Every entry in the search moves the content in <main> to go up one click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, scroll, event-bubbling

The basic layout of my code looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 .....
 ..... 
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <%= form_tag("/search",
        method: :get,
        id:  "Search") do %>
          
          <%= search_field_tag("s",
                params[:s],
                placeholder: "search here",
                ) %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
 <main>
   <%= yield %>
 </main>
 <div class="footer> ....</div>
</body>
```

Every key stroke on the search causes the content in `<main>` to scroll up a bit, as if an `arrow-up` key is pressed.

Any clues to how to prevent "scrolling" the main while entering search string would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Tried `evt.preventDefault()` in the JS for search for `onChange`. Also tried `evt.stopPropogation()` in the JS for search. But both did not work. How to stop propogation up?

Comment: It would be great if you can include a jsfiddle to replicate this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turned out that the css for html had `scroll-padding-top`

```
html {
 scroll-padding-top: 2rem;
}
```

Check for `scroll-margin-top` as well if you encounter such a behavior.